# Connecting two graphs

Tags: tensorflow

Let's say I have two distinct graphs:
first one containing x and y:
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1)), 
y = 2*x,
second one containing a and b:
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1)), 
b = 2*x.

Now, I want to connect the two graphs, by adding some "identity link" between y and a. In other words, I want to tell the second graph to take its input (a) from some node in the first graph(y). It is handy in situations where you don't have the code to recreate the second graph, you just deserialized it from somewhere. One way to do it is using Session.run to compute the output of the first graph, then feed it to the Session.run call that computes the output of the second graph, but there must be some clean way of doing that.

Thanks!

Comment: Any success with this?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly this should work for you ?

It utilizes `tf.import_graph_def` for the job

We have `x` and then feed to the first graph to get `y = 2 *x`, 
then we feed `y` to the second graph to get `b = 2 * y`, for `x = 1.0` the following code will produce `4.0` as a result.

```
import tensorflow as tf
FLOAT = tf.float32
tf.reset_default_graph()

def graph_1():
    g = tf.Graph()
    with g.as_default():
        x = tf.placeholder(FLOAT, [], name='x')
        y = tf.multiply(2.0, x, name='y')
    return g

def graph_2():
    g = tf.Graph()
    with g.as_default():
        a = tf.placeholder(FLOAT, [], name='a')
        b = tf.multiply(2.0, a, name='b')
    return g

# x = 1.0
x = tf.constant(1.0, FLOAT, [])
# feed x to graph_1 -> y = 2.0
g1 = graph_1()
[g1_y] = tf.import_graph_def(g1.as_graph_def(), input_map={'x': x}, return_elements=['y:0'])
# feed y to graph_2 -> b = 4.0
g2 = graph_2()
[g2_b] = tf.import_graph_def(g2.as_graph_def(), input_map={'a': g1_y}, return_elements=['b:0'])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run([g2_b]))
```

Notebook: https://gist.github.com/phizaz/21a5454ddc6c2a15c5c0eae91c96cda5

By the way, if either `graph_1` or `graph_2` contains "variables" this will not work ... I have no idea how to initialize those underlying variables so far, any suggestions ?